# p:dataTable get data from column cell with javascript

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highcharts

In my college project I am migrating RichFaces to PrimeFaces 5.1. In RichFaces dataTable show pieChart using HighCharts. In dataTable to get value column outputText and pass to Highchart show chart in dataTable column.This same Process I need in PrimeFaces.

In Richfaces :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        populatePieChartInDataTable()
    }
    function populatePieChartInDataTable() {
        var dataTableId;
        dataTableId = 'studentDataTable';
        generatePieChart(dataTableId, 'studentstatuspiechartdiv');
    }

    function generatePieChart(dataTableId, pieChartContainerDivId) {
        var dataTable;
        var cellElement;
        var pieChartContent;
        var pieChartContainerDynamicId;
        var rowLength;
        var cellLength;
        dataTable = jQuery('table[id$="' + dataTableId + '"]')[0];
        rowLength = dataTable.tBodies[0].rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
            pieChartContainerDynamicId = pieChartContainerDivId + ':' + i;
            cellLength = dataTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
                cellElement = dataTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[j];
                if (cellElement.childNodes.length == 3) {
                    pieChartContent = cellElement.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
                    cellElement.childNodes[1].setAttribute('id', pieChartContainerDynamicId);
                    createPieChartstudentStatus(pieChartContainerDynamicId,
                            pieChartContent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<rich:datascroller id="dataTopScroller" for="studentDataTable" 
                   page="#{student.dashboardDatascrollerIndex}"oncomplete="populatePieChartInDataTable();" reRender="dataTopScroller"/>
<rich:dataTable id="studentDataTable" value="#{student.responderDashboardDetailList}">
    <rich:column style="width: 325px;">
        <h:outputText id="pieChartData" value="#{student.pieChartData}" style="display: none;"/>
        <f:verbatim><div id="studentStatusPiechartdiv" style="width: 300px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
        </f:verbatim><f:verbatim>
            </div></f:verbatim>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

My doubt In primefaces I use Paginator to show records 10 to 10. In Primefaces script to get dataTable  total number of row length and dataTable cell outputText of pieChartData column value get like above script code and Pass to higchart function.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to the core. It is in essence not charts related. And all you need to do is correct your for loops in javascript and the jquery selectors since PrimeFaces renders a datatable differently than RichFaces. All info is in the **generated** html client side

Comment: @Kukeltje Then how to get datatTable row Length and table cell value()?

Comment: That is plain jquery/javascript and not PrimeFaces related. Just look at the generated html… or post that, remove the PrimeFaces, jsf and highcharts tags and add a javascript  and jquery tag. Did you see btw you posted server side **richfaces**?.